# Assign resource to a class property from trait method

Tags: php, oop, traits

I've decided to write a trait that will be responsable to connect and disconnect from ftp using the php built in functions. I want to login, connect and disconnect to the host by using trait methods.

I need to use `$this->conn` from inside the instance of the class to use the ftp functions. The variable will hold the ftp connection. I want to assign to `$this->conn` the value returned from the connect trait method. I want to know if there is a way to call it inside the class.

I'm unable to get the `$this` variable inside the class that will use the trait. How can I access it inside the class?

```
<?php
trait ConnectionHelper
{
    public function connect(string $host, string $user, string $pwd)
    {
        $this->conn = ftp_connect($host);
        if ($this->conn && ftp_login($this->conn, $user, $pwd)) {
            ftp_pasv($this->conn, true);
            echo "Connected to: $host !";
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
    public function disconnect()
    {
        return ftp_close($this->conn);
    }
}

class FTPManager
{
    use ConnectionHelper;
    private $url;
    private $user;
    private $password;

    /* Upload */
    public function upload(array $inputFile, string $dir = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($dir)) {
            ftp_chdir($this->conn, "/$dir/");
        }
        $upload = ftp_put($this->conn, $inputFile['name'], $inputFile['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY);
        if ($upload) {
            echo 'File uploaded!';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

NB: Can be a good solution to call the connect method of the trait inside the class constructor?

```php
<?php
class myclass{

use mytrait;

public function __construct(){
    $this->conn = $this->connect($host, $user, $pass);
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traits can be used to do what you want, but it would be better to actually use traits for what they can do: assign and read from class properties.

In the trait, when you assign to `$this->conn`:

```
$this->conn = ftp_connect($host);
```

The property is defined for the class instances that use the trait. As such, no need to use `$this->conn = $this->connect()` because `$this->conn` will already contain the connection resource.

So in the constructor, simply call the connect method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->connect($host, $user, $pass);
    // $this->conn will now contain the connection made in connect()
}
```

No need to `return $this->conn;` in the trait. To make sure you free your resource, call `disconnect()` from `FTPManager`'s destructor:

```
public function __destruct()
{
    $this->disconnect();
}
```

---

That being said, it is a rather quirky way of managing this. Having to manually call `connect()` in every class that use the trait is error prone, and might lead to maintainability issue (every one of those class need to be aware of ftp credentials, for instance, tightly coupling them to configuration).

Thinking about it, these class instances are not dependant upon ftp credentials, they are dependant upon *an active ftp connection*. As such, it's way cleaner to actually ask for the ftp connection in the class's constructor, and not bother about calling `connect()` and `disconnect()` in every class that actually needs the ftp connection.

We could think of a connection wrapper class that would greatly simplify things here:

```
class FTPWrapper {
    private $connection;
    public function __construct(string $host, string $user, string $pwd)
    {
        $this->connect($host, $user, $pwd);
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->disconnect();
    }
    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->connection;
    }
    private function connect(string $host, string $user, string $pwd): void
    {
        $this->connection = ftp_connect($host);
        if ($this->connection && ftp_login($this->connection, $user, $pwd)) {
            ftp_pasv($this->connection, true);
            echo "Connected to: $host !";
        }
    }
    private function disconnect(): void
    {
        ftp_close($this->conn);
    }
}
```

Then, inject that wrapper into whatever class that needs to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think that I will rewrite the code to put the connection function inside the ftp class constructor. I was thinking to use a trait because I want to let the user insert the ftp account info every time the related app run, like a login. This will make me to have the problem that my ftp class is instantiated only if the ftp "login" form is submitted.